# providing cucumber test report name through maven command

Tags: spring-boot, maven, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

In my pom.xml I have created different profile for smoke and regression test using cucumber framework. The using the below maven command to run the tests. Following is an example of smoke test:

```
mvn clean test -Psmoke-test -Dcucumber.options="--plugin html:target/cucumber/smoke-test-report.html"
```

The test is running fine, but it is not generating the report even if I provided the `-Dcucumber.options` I am using a common runner class for cucumber, so I cannot give the file name as part of the `@CucumberOptions` annotation.

Following is the pom.xml confguration:

```
<profile>
        <id>smoke-test</id>
        <properties>
            <test>AutomationTestTrigger</test>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <spring.profiles.active>automation-test</spring.profiles.active>
                            <cucumber.filter.tags>@smokeTest</cucumber.filter.tags>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>regression-test</id>
        <properties>
            <test>AutomationTestTrigger</test>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <spring.profiles.active>automation-test</spring.profiles.active>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: cucumber.options was removed. Use the dedicated properties for everything https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/core#properties-environment-variables-system-options

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje Thanks. I tried like this. But it is producing empty report:

`mvn clean test -Psmoke-test -Dcucumber.plugin="pretty, json:target/cucumber/report.json"`

can you please check if this is correct usage

Comment: Looks alright. Make sure you actually select tests in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

Your POM should be like this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>execution</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <projectName>BDD-Automation</projectName>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                    <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
                    <jsonFiles>
                        <param>**/*.json</param>
                    </jsonFiles>
                </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
```

And command you can use like this:
**mvn test -Dtest=Runner verify**